# How to read back the updated Pandas dataframe from Tkinter GUI in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, tkinter-layout

For below code snippet I am able to get the pandas dataframe displayed on Tkinter GUI. However ,after I update the table graphically , i want to read the updated dataframe in tkinter.
How to do that ?

```
PARAMETERS - list of dictionaries.

def UpdateVisualTable():
        global labelframe2 , df
        labelframe2 = LabelFrame(GUITopFrame, text=" Database", bg="white", fg="black")
        labelframe2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    
        frame = tkinter.Frame(labelframe2)
        frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        df = pd.DataFrame(PARAMETERS)

        PandasTable = Table(frame, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
        PandasTable.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what is this `Table` class

Comment: It is list of dictionaries , which is converted to pandas dataframe and displayed visually.

Refer below code:

 df = pd.DataFrame(ListofDictionaries)
PandasTable = Table(frame, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=True)
PandasTable.show()

Comment: You still didnt provide code for the table class